# How to import component in to a Service class in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create an Angular dialog box. For that, I am importing a component into a Service class but  I am getting the below error. I am using a different module and have added an entry component on that module

> Error: No component factory found for NewPasswordComponent. Did you
>   add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

**newpasword/newpassword.module.ts**

```
   import { NewPasswordRoutingModule  } from './newpassword- 
   routing.module';
   import { NewPasswordComponent  } from './newpassword.component';

   export * from './newpassword.component';

    @NgModule({
    imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NewPasswordRoutingModule

    FlexLayoutModule.withConfig({addFlexToParent: false})
   ],
    exports: [
    NewPasswordComponent
    ], 
 declarations: [NewPasswordComponent],
entryComponents: [NewPasswordComponent],

 })
 export class NewPasswordModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppRoutingModule} from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {SomeService} from "./shared/someservice.service";


 @NgModule({
  declarations: [
   AppComponent,

   ],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
 AppRoutingModule,

  ],

 providers: [SomeService],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
   export class AppModule { }
```

shared/someservice.service.ts

```
   import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA,MatDialogConfig} from 
  '@angular/material/dialog';
   import { NewPasswordComponent  } from 
   '../newPassword/newpassword.component';
   @Injectable()
  export class SomeService  {

 constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {
 }




 LogIn(){


      let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewPasswordComponent>;
               const config = new MatDialogConfig();;
              config.role = 'dialog';
               config.width = '60%';
                config.data = { newpassword:  that.newpassword };
             dialogRef = that.dialog.open(NewPasswordComponent, config);
 console.log("Dialog Start"+email);

   dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
   that.newpassword = result;
     console.log("Dialog closed"+result);
  });

 }


 }
```

I am getting the below error. I have added entry component in a password module but still getting this error

> Error: No component factory found for NewPasswordComponent. Did you
>   add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Comment: Are you using lazy loading?

Comment: Yes I am using lazy loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the behaviour you are observing is described in that [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14324): entry components of a lazy loaded module are not available at the root level injector.

So you need to provide the service that uses the entry component in your `NewPasswordModule`, not in `AppModule`.

If you are looking for a more generic approach (say you want to use that service in many lazy loaded modules), you could have a look at this [suggested solution](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14324#issuecomment-444557664), which creates a generic service, which is then inherited and provided in 
 lazy loaded feature modules.

Answer (score 1):

Import the `NewPasswordModule` to `AppModule` module

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  NewPasswordModule
 ],
```

Comment: @No it's not working I am getting compile time error "There are multiple modules with names that only differ in a casing"